# Properness for small forcings

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

It is easy to see a forcing of size $\aleph_1$ is proper if and only if is semiproper. I was wondering when such an equivalency holds between semi-proper and stationary-preserving forcings in $\rm ZFC$? Or consistently in a model where significant fragments of $\rm MM$ fail.

Comment: If you replace $\aleph_1$ by $\aleph_0$, then there is a simple answer.

Comment: Yep, that universal answer! you can even prove more

Comment: Maybe related: [Collapsing ω2 with semi-proper forcing](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00153-017-0588-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, as the following upcoming work of Shelah and Usuba shows:

**Theorem (Shelah-Usuba)**:
The following theories are equiconsistent with ZFC:

ZFC+CH+ “there is an $\omega _1$-stationary preserving $\sigma$-Baire poset of size $\aleph_1$
​    which is not semiproper”.

ZFC+“Martin’s axiom for semiproper posets of size $\aleph_1$” + “there is an $\omega _1$-stationary preserving $\sigma$-Baire poset of size $\aleph_1$ which is not semiproper”.

ZFC+CH+“every $\omega _1$-stationary preserving $\sigma$-Baire poset of size $\aleph_1$ is semiproper”.

See [$\omega_1$-Stationary preserving $\sigma$-Baire posets of size $\aleph_1$](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/1010/).